# why define "SQLITE_EXTERN extern"

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

In sqlite's source code, you can see following define:

```
/*
** Add the ability to override 'extern'
*/
#ifndef SQLITE_EXTERN
# define SQLITE_EXTERN extern
#endif
```

I am not quite sure in what case we might want to override "extern", do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are telling the compiler to replace all instances of SQLITE_EXTERN with the "extern" keyword, when it preprocesses files. Hence if you includes a sql header which contains a declaration as below

SQLITE_EXTERN datatype sql_variable;

the compiler treats it as an "extern" variable and doesn't allocate memory for the variable.

EDIT:

To add to that, it is a convention to declare variables with "extern" in the header files and defining the variable in the cpp file. Defining variables in the header files without "extern" qualifier would allocate space for the variable wherever the header file is included!

Overriding the extern:

The #define above provides an ability for you to initialize sql variables as you like. See the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w7wd1177(v=vs.71).aspx for more details about initializers. There is a statement in the article ->

> Declarations of automatic, register, static, and external variables can contain initializers. However, declarations of external variables can contain initializers only if the variables are not declared as extern.

If you somehow want to override the external declaration of an sql variable, and want to initialize it by yourself, you could just define

```
#define SQLITE_EXTERN
```

One reason to override this is because Sqlite is cross platform (really widely), some of the platform may not support extern keywords well, thus we need to flexibility to disable this.

and init the variables as you want them. Hope this helps!

Comment: Sure it is, but the question is why we need this extra define, as the comment says it want to add the ability to override "extern", when do we want to override?

Comment: Thanks Chethan, but I am afraid you edit doesn't answer the question either. You are talking about the usage of "extern".

Comment: @baiyanhuang - Whenever we *don't* want `extern`, or when we need some additional system specific specifier. :-)

Comment: @Bo Persson: I doubt about the really world application of this, can you give an example? you can't just remove a extern without code chagne, or else there will be compiler errors.

Comment: @baiyanhuang - But you might want to have `extern __cdecl` or `extern __dllimport` with some compilers. The developer wants to have this option, presumably because he belives there is a need sometimes. Configuration macros are often used to fix small differences between compilers or operating systems.

Comment: I am completely not sure but its got something to do with object initializers! Let me post an edit now. I hope this should answer your question!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to override the define for example if you want to put the sqlite library into a  dll (platform specific), in which case `extern` would become a `__declspec(dllimport)`.

Just one possible case. I guess there might be others as well.

Comment: Have you ever use this trick in your project, or have you ever seem any open source project using this?

Comment: If you change the extern to __declspec(dllimport), it might be ok for reference from code outside the dll, but for code inside the dll, because you remove the extern, there would be problems.

Comment: Yeah well, it leads to some sort of nasty #ifdef/#else/#etcpp orgy that is usually put to some *conf.h file (e.g. zconf.h for the zlib example). I never said it'd be nice code, though :-)

Comment: Hmm, then this trick doesn't have any reason to exist~~~ I hope sqlite do this for a reason...

Comment: Well it does as you are able to change the code by setting the define and put up your own processing. That is much easier (and way less error prone) than going through every source file of sqlite and **manually** change every extern to what ever you need, isn't it?